# Angular2 , link to SCSS Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, sass

I need help with adding bootstrap 3.3.7 SASS version to my Angular 2 project. I created that project with Angular CLI with SCSS precompiler, so .scss are my default style files. I downloaded Bootstrap SCSS version but i don't know how to link it to my project. I tried to move folder that Bootstrap which I've got to my project folder than i link it in index.html, it doesn't work , i tried to import that bootstrap to my `styles.scss` main file but it doesn't work as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please check the this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/630)